# Фильтрация (форма поиска + чекбоксы с категориями) на ajax jquery php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Имеется БД с базой блюд. Используя input делаю сортировку при вводе слов с помощью ajax.

```
function search_dishes($rest, $Name){
global $db;
if($Name != ""){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE (CategPath LIKE '%$rest%') and (Name LIKE '%$Name%') ORDER BY Ident ASC";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE (CategPath LIKE '%$rest%') ORDER BY Ident ASC";
}
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$dishes = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $dishes[] = $row;
}
return $dishes;}
```

Далее выполняю функцию и передаю ее в js

```
 function fill(Value) {
   $('#search').val(Value);
   $('#display').hide();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#search").keyup(function() {
       var name = $('#search').val();
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: {
                   search: name
               }, 
               success: function(html) {
                   $("#display").html(html).show();
               }
           });
   });
});
```

На данном этапе все работает, но к этому коду нужно добавить фильтрацию с чекбоксами из определенных категорий, чтобы отбор работал одновременно

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checktag[]" value="<?=$tag['Tags']?>" id="toggle_<?=$tag['Id']?>">
```

Запрос меняю на

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE (CategPath LIKE '%$rest%') and (Name LIKE '%$Name%') and (genWebMenu LIKE '%$tag%') ORDER BY Ident ASC";
```

Если обернуть чекбоксы в форму с submit и написать подобное, то на новой странице я получу нужную фильтрацию

```
if(isset($_POST['checktag'])){
  $checktag = $_POST['checktag'];
  $tag_string = implode(" ", $checktag);
  echo $tag_string;

  $dishes = get_dish_tag($tag_string);
```

Вопрос - как использовать вместе чекбоксы и фильтрацию в поле search и одновременно без перезагрузки страницы делать отбор. с Jquery, как и с JS в целом не знаком в принципе, но думаю, что нужно делать что-то подобное

```
 $("input.checkbox").on('change', function ()
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: можно ajax-запрос сделать отдельной функцией именованной, в нее дописать проверку чекбоксов, и эту функцию вызывать и по вводу в поле, и по клику на чекбокс.

Comment: Спасибо. Я приблизительно понимаю о чем речь, но в реализации возникают сложности. Видимо нужно будет углубляться в Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно ajax-запрос сделать отдельной функцией именованной, в нее дописать проверку чекбоксов, и эту функцию вызывать и по вводу в поле, и по клику на чекбокс.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').on('input', getDishes);
  $('input.dishes_filter').on('click', getDishes);
});

var getDishes = function(){
  let request_data = {'filters': [], 'name': $('#search').val() };
  $('input.dishes_filter').each(function(e, elem){
    if( $(elem).is(':checked') ){
      request_data['filters'].push( $(elem).val() );
    }
  });
  
  // массив request_data готов для отправки серверу
  console.log(request_data);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" value="filter1" class="dishes_filter" />
<input type="checkbox" value="filter2" class="dishes_filter" />
<input type="checkbox" value="filter3" class="dishes_filter" />
```

Теперь ajax запрос (после или вместо строчки `console.log(request_data);`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ваш/скрипт.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {filters: request_data},  // отправляем массив в php
    success: function(html){
      $("#display").html(html).show();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, msg){
        console.log(jqXHR); console.log(msg+' '+status);
    }
});
```

Теперь в php получаем массив:

```
$formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
$filters = $formdata['filters'];
```

И формируем запрос как-то так. Вообще, лучше бы использовать подготовленные выражения, но сейчас не суть важно.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE Name LIKE '%".$filters['name']."%'";
foreach($filters['filters'] as $filter){
   $query .= " AND CategPath LIKE '%$filter%'";
}
$query .= " ORDER BY Ident ASC";
```

Comment: Спасибо, Максим. Буду дальше разбираться как вызывать ajax в данном случае и правильно составить sql запрос

Comment: я немного дописал ответ, посмотрите, может как-то поможет пример.

Comment: То есть не понимаю что нужно писать в поле data при обработке js с помощью ajax, да и еще кучу мелких вещей. Ваш код рабочий, поэтому остальные вопросы у меня уже от полного незнания предмета. Нужно учить или лучше находить наставника, который захочет со мной мучиться. Еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хорошо, Максим, сейчас попробую что-то сделать с этим кодом. Так вроде бы с виду понятней

Comment: Я там в php опустил проверку данных, но сам принцип думаю должен быть понятен. В `$filters = $formdata['filters'];` получаем массив той-же структуры, что и нам в консоле выводится. И его уже обрабатываем как душе угодно.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, в массив попадает значение и инпута, и чекбоксов.
`if($Name != ""){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE (CategPath LIKE '%$rest%') and (Name LIKE '%".$filters['name']."%')"; 
  foreach($filters['filters'] as $filter){
  $query .= " AND genWebMenu LIKE '%".$filters['name']."%')";
  }
  $query .= " ORDER BY Ident ASC";
 } else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM MenuItems WHERE (CategPath LIKE '%$rest%') ORDER BY Ident ASC";
 }`
Вопрос в чем - строка и чекбоксы - разные колонки в myqsl. Оно будет искать и там, и там, вот примерно такой код, как выше?

Comment: @ЕвгенийК все верно, только `AND genWebMenu LIKE '%".$filter['name']."%')`у вас . Ну вы если нажмете кнопку `выполнить код` под моим ответом и пощелкаете, то в консоли увидите массив. Вот этот массив в таком же виде и отправится в php

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, извиняюсь за тупые вопросы.

Comment: это я вас запутал, переменные называть, конечно, нужно не торопясь. В итоге у нас путанице. В общем, так: в начале, в `$filters = $formdata['filters'];` у нас массив, тот, который в консоли. теперь как получить значения полей: `$filters['name']` - это инпут с именем. `$filters['filters']` - это массив с чекбовсами.

Comment: Ну запутать меня легко, потому что знаю на базовом уровне php, еще меньше js, а вот ajax и jquery совсем первый раз вижу по сути. Отсюда и столько вопросов.
Получается, запрос будет все же примерно вот таким, раз использовался `foreach`
`foreach($filters['filters'] as $filter){
  $query .= " AND genWebMenu LIKE '%".$filter."%')";`

Comment: да, точно, все правильно вы сейчас написали. тут в `$filter` уже искомое значение.

Comment: Хотел написать вам в личку, но не нашел такой функции на сайте... Может дадите какой-то совет в плане обучения и развития в данной сфере? Что читать, смотреть? А то инфы на просторах инета очень много

Comment: @ЕвгенийК честно говоря, тут я не гуру, могу только подсказать что помогло мне и показалось понятным. Если по PHP, то `Котеров PHP7` мне понравилась или, если уж совсем с азов, то чудная книжка `Мориссон.М-Изучаем PHP и MySQL`. По javascript:  `learn.javascript.ru` онлайн учебник-справочник. По php совет - вначале разберитесь, как работает PDO + подотовленные запросы, и к БД обращайтесь через PDO. Это не сложно, но если не сделать, потом замучаетесь переписывать кучу кода с `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Максим. Займусь php значит для начала.
По данной теме код весь заменил, но ничего не происходит при вводе в строку или щелчке по чебоксам. Буду искать где ошибся

Comment: Если не получится, скиньте на stepanovm77@yandex.ru файлы ваши и желательно бы еще хотя бы структуру таблицы бд, я вечером после работы отправлю Вам рабочий пример.

Comment: спасибо. ну консоль браузера пишет вот так
`POST https://******/filter.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:2
ajax @ jquery.js:2
getDishes @ checkbox.js:14
dispatch @ jquery.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.js:2`

Comment: Да, лучше все-таки ваши файлы отправьте, удалите там секретное) . Так мы тут по одной строчке будем год разбираться, что не работает.